# ошибка в работе парсера

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Ошибки в консоли нет, однако в консоли нет и конечного кода.
Все что выводиться в консоли: `Process finished with exit code 0`
Сам код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse():
    URL = 'https://www.olx.ua/elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.465'
    }
    response = requests.get(URL, HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='offer-wrapper')
    comps = []
    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title': item.find('a', class_='marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink linkWithHashPromoted').get_text,
            'price': item.find('p', class_='price').get_text(strip=True)

        })
    for comp in comps:
        print(f"{comp['title']}")

parse()
```

Comment: Код 0 - значит, ошибок нет. Это значит, что код отработал корректно. То, что помимо этого больше нет никакого выхода, значит, коду нечего выводить для данного входа.

Comment: должна быть ошибка ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чуть поправил ваш код, ошибка была в том что команды `get_text()` нету, только есть `.text` и бс4 не выдел класс ссылки (это бывает, когда класс слишком длинный). Вот сам код который работает:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse():
    URL = 'https://www.olx.ua/elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/'
    # HEADERS = {
    #     'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.465'
    # }
    response = requests.get(URL)  # headers=HEADERS
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='offer-wrapper')
    comps = []
    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title': item.find('h3', class_='lheight22 margintop5').text.strip(),
            'price': item.find('p', class_='price').text.strip()

        })
    for comp in comps:
        print(f"{comp['title']} : {comp['price']}")

parse()
```